# OpenStreetMap Overpass query

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

Im having some issues querying the openstreetmap DB using overpass.

What I want is to get all the nd nodes in a way, so my query is like so:

```
[out:json][timeout:30];
(way(id:397466166);._;>;);
out body center qt 15;
```

This...sorta works. It gives me all the nodes in the way, but they are not in the right order. Ive tried countless queries to try and get the children nodes of the way, but I just can't get it. One query I tried was:

```
[out:json][timeout:30];
(way(id:397466166);<;);
out geom;
```

But this just returns the ways latitude and longitude...

Any help?

Comment: added the `operpass-api` tag; but how is this question related to `android`?

Comment: Im using the maps in my android project, but yes your right it doesn't really apply. Ill remove it

Comment: see https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing &
https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/online_routers

Comment: For the correct order of the nodes you need to look at the *way*. Nodes can be part of more than one way but each way references all of its nodes in the correct order.